# Warum werden Diskussionen in den Chat verschoben? / Why do Discussions get moved to Chat?

Tags: discussion, community-moderation

Gehören Diskussionen unter einer Frage (oder einer Antwort) zu dieser Frage Posting? Schließlich wurden sie auch dort geführt. Dennoch werden sie von Moderator*innen zum Teil in den Chat verschoben, zum Beispiel unter [What greetings were common before “grüß Gott” became universal?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61972/what-greetings-were-common-before-gr%c3%bc%c3%9f-gott-became-universal).

Werden Diskussionen dadurch nicht abgewürgt? Warum machen Moderator*innen das?

---

Do Discussions below a question (or an answer) belong to the question? At least the discussion has been held there. Still, sometimes they are being transferred to chat, for instance at [What greetings were common before “grüß Gott” became universal?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61972/what-greetings-were-common-before-gr%c3%bc%c3%9f-gott-became-universal).

Doesn't this just kill the discussion? Why do mods do this?

Answer (score 5):

*see english translation below*

Die Frage dreht sich letztlich darum, welche Funktion die Kommentare auf der Seite haben und welche Funktion der Chat hat. Dazu gibt es einige Regeln. Ich denke, der Geist dieser Regeln leitet sich daraus ab, dass StackExchange eine Wissenssammlung ist. Anders als in einem reinen Forum liegt hier der Fokus darauf, möglichst klar definierte Fragen mit möglichst guten Antworten zu sammeln.

### Funktion und Stellung der Kommentare

Kommentare sind grundsätzlich nicht dazu gedacht, ewig zu leben, sondern sind für flüchtige Informationen gedacht. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment:

> What are comments? Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

Im Gegensatz dazu ist der Chat beständiger. Kommentare haben einen sehr eng umgrenzte Funktion, wie es im [Help Center - comment everywhere](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) beschrieben ist:

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Kommentare sind insbesondere nicht für Diskussionen gemacht. Die verlinkte Seite sagt:

> When shouldn't I comment? [...] Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;

### Bezug des Chats zur Frage

Wenn Kommentare in den Chat verschoben werden, wird dafür ein eigener Chat-Raum eröffnet. Chat-Raum und Frage sind in beide Richtungen verlinkt. Der Bezug wird also nicht aufgehoben.

Allerdings findet durchaus eine Hierarchisierung statt - weil man den Chat nur mit einem zusätzlichen Klick erreicht, und die Kommentare sofort sichtbar sind. Diese Hierarchisierung ist aber gerade gewünscht: Die Seite der Frage soll möglichst auf die Frage und die Antworten fokussiert sein - das leitet sich aus dem ganz oben beschriebenen Charakter von SE als Wissenssammlung ab. Kommentare und Chat sind in dieser Perspektive Rauschen, das vom eigentlich Relevanten ablenkt. Das ist ein Grund, warum die Kommentare grundsätzlich als flüchtig konzipiert sind - das ist eine Dienstleistung an die (auch zukünftigen) Leser*innen der Wissenssammlung. Wer neu auf eine Frage stößt, soll die Frage lesen können, und die Antwort unumwunden erhalten können; man soll nicht genötigt werden, lange Kommentar-Diskussionen zu lesen, um sich sicher zu sein, alles für die Antwort Relevante erfasst zu haben.

Daher ist das Einzige, was immer und ewig mit der Frage verknüpft sein sollte, die Antworten.

### Funktionalität des Chats

Die Diskussion kann ohne Weiteres im Chat fortgesetzt werden. Daher denke ich nicht, dass die Diskussion dadurch abgewürgt wird - jede*r User*in von german.SE hat ja automatisch auch einen entsprechenden Chat-Account.

Alles, was man mit Kommentaren machen kann, kann man auch im Chat machen (wenn man bereit ist, den Stern als Ersatz für den Kommentar-Upvote zu verwenden). Im Chat kann man sogar noch mehr, weil man direkt auf Beiträge antworten kann, was in Kommentaren nicht möglich ist.

### Bewertung des Chats als grundsätzlich minderwertiges Medium

Der Chat ist auch nicht per se ein minderwertiges Medium. Der beim Verschieben enstehende Chat-Raum ist nicht für "Tratsch und Kaffeekränzchen" gedacht, sondern thematisch eng an das Posting gebunden.  Ein persönlicher Angriff ist mit dem Verschieben der Kommentare in den Chat nicht verbunden - es handelt sich einfach darum, wie Chat und Kommentare hier organisiert werden.

---

At the end of the day, this is dealing with what functions do comments and chat have (or: are supposed to have) on this site. There are some rules about this. These rules are mostly inspired by the idea that StackExchange is a knowledge database. In difference to a forum, it's focussing on collecting good questions and best answers.

### Function of the comments

Basically, comments are not made to live forever. They are thought to provide rather ephemeral information. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment:

> What are comments? Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

To the contrary, the chat is more long-living. The function of comments is defined quite narrowly, as described in [Help Center - comment everywhere](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Especially, comments are not made for discussion. The linked page states:

> When shouldn't I comment? [...] Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;

### Relation of Chat and Question

Whenever a mod transfers a thread of comments into the chat, a dedicated chat-room is being opened for this, while chat-room and question are being linked to each other in both directions. That means that transferring comments to the chat does not break the relation between question and discussion.

However, this creates a hierarchy of information - because you can reach that chat only with one additional click, while the comments are immediately visible. This hierarchy is actually intended: The question page is supposed to focus on the question and its answers - this is a result of the general idea of SE being a knowledge database. In this perspective, comments and chat are noise, which distract focus off the most relevant things. This is one reason why comments are designed to be transient - it is a service to the readers of the site (including future readers): Whoever reads a question is supposed to get the answer directly, without the need to untangle a possibly complex thread of discussion. Readers should not need to read this to be sure to get the full picture. That'swhy the only thing that should be connected witht the question forever, is the answers.

### Functionality of the Chat

The discussion can be continued in Chat without problems. Hence I don't believe that the discussion is getting killed by being transferred to caht. Any profile on german.SE also has a chat-account automatically.

Anything which can be done with comments, can as well be done in the chat (as long as one is wiling to use the star as a replacement for upvoting a comment). The chat has even more powerful functionality, since it is possible to answer directly on a post - a thing that is impossible in comments.

### Is the Chat a Mediocre Means of Communcation per se?

No. The chat-room coming into existence when the discussion is moved, is not meant to be used for chit-chatting, but is closely related to the issue. Please don't feel personally offended, when your discussion is moved to chat. This is just the way how comments and chat are being organized here.

Comment: Gegen eine Fortsetzung der Diskussion im Chat spricht nichts. Ich halte es aber für falsch, bereits unterhalb einer Frage oder Antwort gepostete Kommentare ohne Einverständnis des Verfassers an einen Ort zu verschieben, an dem sie nicht verfasst wurden. Ich kann aus den zitierten Sätzen des Help Centers auch nicht herauslesen, dass Moderatoren dazu animiert werden sollen, laufende themenkonforme Diskussionen in belanglosen Chat umzuwandeln und von dort zu entfernen, wo die Diskussion geführt wurde. Wer mag, kann ja gerne zusätzlich auch im Chat darüber plaudern. ...

Comment: ... Es gibt ja auch einen Unterschied zwischen einer offiziellen Besprechung, die in einem Besprechungszimmer stattfindet und vorher im Kalender aller Mitarbeiter eingetragen war, und dem Tratsch in der Teeküche. Der Chat ist der Trasch in der Teeküche, die Kommentare unterhalb von Fragen und Antworten sind Beiträge in der offiziellen Besprechung, die aus gutem Grund - Im Unterscheid zur Pausenplauderei - auch im Protokoll aufscheinen.

Comment: *»Kommentare sind grundsätzlich nicht dazu gedacht, ewig zu leben, sondern sind für flüchtige Informationen gedacht.«* Womit begründest du diese Aussage? Ich halte sie nämlich für grundlegend falsch. Genau das Gegenteil ist wahr. In Kommentaren steckt sehr viel Wissen. Dieses Wissen an eine ungeeignete Stelle zu verschieben, ist, wie wenn sich ein Sachbuch kauft, und dort dann steht, dass dieses und jenes Detail in einem anderen Buch zu finden ist. Das ergänzende Wissen, das in den Kommentaren steckt, muss auf genau der Seite bleiben, auf der es gepostet wurde! ...

Comment: ... Wenn ich auf Stackexchange (egal ob Stack Overflow, Mathematics, Latex, Server Fault, Linguistics, etc.) eine Lösung zu einem gerade aktuellen Problem suche, lese ich **IMMER** auch die Kommentare unter den Antworten, weil diese Kommentare sehr oft wichtige Ergänzungen zur eigentlichen Antwort enthalten. Insbesondere kann man aus dem Kommentaren oft besser die Qualität einer Antwort abschätzen als aus der numerischen Bewertung, weil viele User einfach nur die erstgereihten Antworten bewerten, also jene, die ohnehin schon viele Punkte haben, und gute und exzellente Antworten, ...

Comment: ... die erst später verfasst wurden, kaum gelesen werden. Diese Antworten werden aber kommentiert, und genau diese Kommentare, die zum Glück NICHT flüchtig sind, enthalten sehr viel Wissen, das jenes Wissen, das in den Antworten selbst steckt, hervorragend ergänzt und schmerzlich fehlen würde, wenn es gelöscht oder verschoben würde. 
Daher müssen neben den Antworten auch die Kommentare »für immer und ewig« auf der jeweiligen Seite bestehen bleiben. ...

Comment: ... Ich käme auch niemals auf die Idee, im Chat nach weiteren Informationen zu den Themen auf dieser Seite zu suchen, abgesehen davon, dass ich gar nicht wüsste, wie man in diesem unübersichtlichen Chat danach suchen soll. (Ich will mir auch gar nicht die Mühe machen, das herauszufinden.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das Wissen _sollte_ aber nicht in den Kommentaren stecken, sondern in den Antworten. Auch die Bewertung _sollte_ nicht in den Kommentaren landen, sondern in den Votes. Genau das ist der Punkt. Es geht um Übersichtlichkeit.

Comment: Mehrere Millionen User (mich eingeschlossen) sehen das anders. Es gibt zwei Möglichkeiten, damit umzugehen: 1. Die Betreiber und Moderatoren pochen stur auf selbstgewählten Definitionen, die von ihren Usern seit Bestehen der Site konsequent ignoriert werden, nur um damit die User zu verärgern, die sich ja eh nicht daran halten. Oder 2. Die Betreiber und Moderatoren gestehen sich ein, dass nicht alles, was sie sich wünschen, von den Usern gelebt wird, passen ihre Definitionen an die Realität an und machen die Welt zu einem besseren Ort.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast nope. Es gibt genau *eine* Möglichkeit: Du stellst das Thema **übergreifend** zur Debatte indem Du auf Meta SE postest. Über die Umsetzung auf einer einzelnen Site zu schimpfen ist wie in einem Bundesland über Regeln zu debattieren, die staatsweit gelten, oder in einer Abteilung über die Policy eines ganzen Konzerns. Und ja, Du solltest sehr gut argumentieren, warum Du das Fass aufmachen willst und warum die Frage kein Duplicate ist.

Comment: Die Kommentare werden doch nicht kommentarlos (pun not intended) abgeschoben, sondern es wird ein Link zum Chat dagelassen. Der interessierte Leser hat also jederzeit die Möglichkeit dort nachzulesen. @HubertSchölnast woher nimmst du die Zahl "mehrere Millionen Nutzer"?

Comment: @infinitezero »woher nimmst du die Zahl "mehrere Millionen Nutzer"?« von hier: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all Links unten siehst du, dass diese User-Liste 367036 Seiten hat, und auf jeder Seite stehen 36 User. 36*367036 = ca. 13,2 Millionen User.

Comment: Und woher kommt die Folgerung, dass die das alle so sehen wie Du?

Comment: Wie lustig, dass wir hier wieder in einer Präskriptivismus/Deskriptivismus-Debatte enden.

Answer (score 0):

**Begriffsklärung:**
Jede Seite auf German-SE hat einen Titel in großer Schrift und darunter das Eröffnungs-Posting in normal großer Schrift. Beide zusammen (Titel und Eröffnungs-Posting) bilden die **Frage,** die das Thema der Seite festlegt.
Diese Frage kann durch mehrere Postings beantwortet werden, die dasselbe Layout wie das Eröffnungs-Posting verwenden. Diese Postings heißen **Antworten.**
Für Fragen und Antworten verwende ich hier den Sammelbegriff **Posting.**
Unterhalb von Postings, also auf derselben Seite, können **Kommentare** gepostet werden, die in kleinerer Schrift erschienen, mit weniger Layout-Möglichkeiten auskommen müssen und auf maximal 600 Zeichen begrenzt sind. Jeder Kommentar hat durch seine Lage unterhalb eines Postings einen eindeutigen Bezug zu genau einem Posting (bezieht sich also entweder auf die Frage oder auf genau eine der Antworten)
Der **Chat** ist ein separater Bereich auf stackexchange.com, der sich nicht auf derselben Seite wie die Postings und Kommentare befindet.

**Meine Kritik am Chat**
Ein themenoffener Chat ist etwas gänzlich anderes als themenbezogene Kommentare. Zu chatten bedeutet, dass man sich schriftlich in Echtzeit und mit anderen Menschen unterhält, ohne in der Wahl des Themas irgendwelchen Beschränkungen zu unterliegen. Im Vordergrund steht die themenoffene zwischenmenschliche Kommunikation, nicht mehr die lösungsorientierte Arbeit an einem vorgegebenen Thema.

Die Diskussionen, die im Stackexchange-Chat stattfinden, sind auf der Seite, auf der die Postings stehen, nicht sichtbar. Befindet man sich im Chat, sieht man nur den Chatverlauf und darüber den Titel und die ersten ca. 300 Zeichen des Eröffnungspostings. Im Chat sieht man also weder das ganze themengebende Posting, noch alle anderen Postings, die zur selben Frage gehören. Der Kontext ist also nur rudimentär und indirekt verfügbar. In einem Chat stört das aber auch gar nicht, weil dort der Kontext und das Thema ohnehin keine wichtige Rolle spielen. Durch ein Verschieben der Kommentare in den Chat wird bewirkt, dass die Bindung an das Thema aufgehoben wird.

Smalltalk ist nicht mein Ding, deshalb chatte ich auch sonst nicht im Internet. Mich interessiert ganz einfach nicht, was andere Leute vor 10 Minuten gegessen haben, oder ob ihnen die Zahnpasta von der Bürste gefallen ist. Ich will auf German-SE Fragen beantworten und an sachbezogenen Diskussionen zu Fragen und Antworten teilnehmen. Ich will nicht chatten. Die Verschiebung von Kommentaren in den Chat empfinde ich daher auch als grobe Unhöflichkeit, denn dadurch werden die Kommentare nicht nur von dem auslösenden Thema getrennt, sondern auch abgewertet. Engagierte und zielgerichtete Diskussionsbeiträge werden zu belangloser Plauderei degradiert.

Jeder Kommentar ist an ein ganz bestimmtes Posting gebunden, und wurde mit der Gewissheit verfasst, an Ort und Stelle ebenso lange erhalten zu bleiben wie dieses Posting. Insbesondere hat jeder Kommentar einen klar erkennbaren Bezug zu diesem Posting, der jedoch verloren geht, wenn er auf eine andere Seite verschoben wird.

**Ich schlage folgende Regelung vor:**

Jeder Kommentar, der sich thematisch mit dem Posting beschäftigt, unterhalb dessen er verfasst wurde, soll während der gesamten Zeitdauer der Existenz des Postings genau dort stehen bleiben, wo er geschrieben wurde. Wichtig ist der Bezug zum Posting, nicht die Anzahl der schon publizierten Kommentare. Auch wenn unterhalb eines Postings 50 oder 80 Kommentare gepostet wurden, die sich alle mit genau dem Thema beschäftigen, das im Posting aufgeworfen wurde, müssen diese Kommentare dort bleiben, wo sie aufgrund ihres Bezugs zum Thema hingehören. Denn es hat in so einem Fall ja einen guten Grund, warum man sich so intensiv mit diesem Thema befasst, und so lange Diskussionen sind ja auch nicht der Regelfall.

Wenn ein Kommentar völlig ohne Bezug zum Thema gepostet wurde (z.B Spam), ganz offensichtlich irrtümlich gepostet wurde, gesetzwidrig ist, oder wenn er klar erkennbar darauf abzieht, jemanden auf der persönlichen Ebene anzugreifen, ist er ohne Vorwarnung zu löschen. Ebenso allfällige Nachfolgekommentare, die sich auf den zu löschenden Kommentar beziehen. Im Zweifelsfall sollte der fragliche Kommentar stehen bleiben. (German-SE wird nicht an einigen wenigen fragwürdigen Kommentaren zugrunde gehen. Die User sind in der überwiegenden Mehrheit sehr diszipliniert.)

Wenn sich die ursprünglich themenbezogene Diskussion vom eigentlichen Thema abwendet, und beginnt sich um ein Thema zu drehen, das keinen direkten Bezug mehr zum Thema des Postings hat, sollten die Teilnehmer des Off-Topic-Zweigs der Diskussion verwarnt werden und dazu aufgefordert werden, sich wieder dem eigentlichen Thema zuzuwenden oder sich in den Chat zu begeben, wo es keine Themenbindung gibt. Am einfachsten könnte diese Verwarnung durch einen entsprechenden Kommentar eines Moderator geschehen. Off-Topic-Kommentare, die **nach** dieser Warnung gepostet werden, können dann von einem Moderator gelöscht werden.

**In keinem Fall** darf aber ein Kommentar, der sich inhaltlich mit dem Thema des Postings befasst, und der weder beleidigend noch gesetzwidrig ist, von diesem Posting wegbewegt werden!

Eine Verschiebung eines bereits getätigten Kommentars auf eine andere Seite scheint mir in keinem einzigen Szenario angebracht und sinnvoll zu sein.

Comment: Und was sollen die genauen Kriterien sein? Ab wann gilt ein Kommentar als "noch ok" oder als "löschbar"? Da scheint mir am Ende des Tages sehr viel Willkür hinterzustecken. Zumal Löschung auch nicht nachvollziehbar ist. Es fehlt plötzlich einfach. Bei einer Verschiebung in den Chat ist es verlinkt und aufgehoben.

Comment: Ich chatte gerne. Ich chatte dabei vorwiegend mit Menschen, die mir nicht erzählen, dass ihnen die Zahnpasta von der Zahnbürste gefallen ist. Die meisten Chat-Räume in der Stack Exchange Domäne verfolgen zielgerichtet Diskussionen zu bestimmten Themen; natürlich auch mit gelegentlichen Exkursen in angrenzende Bereiche. Ich finde diesen Teil der Antwort geradezu beleidigend (und nicht nur grob unhöflich) gegenüber einer großen Benutzergruppe von Stack Exchange; ja eigentlich müsste mensch prüfen, ob das noch im Rahmen des Code of Conduct ist.

Comment: Abgesehen davon hätte ich von jemanden mit fast einhunderttausend Reputationspunkten ein grundlegendes Verständnis dafür erwartet, wie Stack Exchange funktioniert; und dass Stack Exchange ganz grundsätzlich nicht für Diskussionen ausgelegt ist.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: Es war nicht meine Absicht irgend jemanden zu beleidigen. Dass ich ein grundlegendes Verständnis dafür habe, wie Stack Exchange (SE) funktioniert, bedeutet nicht, dass ich die Art, wie SE funktioniert, in allen Details für optimal halte. Der überwiegende Teil von SE ist einem Zustand sehr nahe, den ich als perfekt bezeichnen würde. Ich persönlich halte aber den Chat für wenig gelungen. Vor allen den Brauch, lebendige Diskussionen zum Sterben dorthin zu verschieben, halte ich für sehr fragwürdig. Wer chatten will, soll das gerne tun, aber man soll bitte niemanden dazu zwingen.

Comment: Ich kann nicht nachvollziehen, was bei dieser Antwort zu Downvotes geführt hat.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so, daher von mir +1.